# rpm-spec and Home's user folder

Tags: rpm, centos-6, rpmbuild

I'm just trying to figure out how to know in an `rpm` package that calls `sudo`, and put some files in the non-root home folder for the users who call `sudo` or are root.

I tried with something like this:

```
%define whoami %(eval who am i | awk '{print $1}')
```

then I try to copy some files to `/home/%{whoami}/target`
after that (and some more instructions) I build the package, without problems, actually can run pretty well the package in my machine, the problem is when I try to run the same package in other machine with a different user name, it doesn't copy the files because it looks for my original home user folder instead of the other user.

Comment: Shouldn't this question be asked on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 0):

RPM packages are installed by root, there is no need to fool around with `sudo` or anything else. Check [Fedora's RPM guidelines](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/index.html) for a detailed explanation of how to create spec files. The guidelines are (mostly) applicable to all RPM-based distributions, and as RHEL (and thus CentOS) are downstream from Fedora, they should apply with only minor fudging for recent updates.